# Watson speech-to-text service how to return language other than English in java

Tags: ibm-cloud, speech-to-text, chinese-locale, ibm-watson

When I try STT Java code with Model set to "zh-CN_BroadbandModel", not able to get expected result.

Here is my sample code:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {

    SpeechToText service = new SpeechToText();
    service.setUsernameAndPassword(USERNAME, PASSWORD);

    File file = new File("C:/IBM/Watson/APIs/speech-to-text/test.wav");

    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put("audio", file);
    params.put("content_type","audio/wav");
    params.put("model", "zh-CN_BroadbandModel");

    SpeechResults transcript = service.recognize(params);

    System.out.println(transcript);
}
```

SpeechResult as below:

```
{"results": [{
      "final": true,
      "alternatives": [
        {"transcript": "?? ? ? ? ?? ? ? ? ?? ??? ? ??? ?? ? ? ?? ?? ? ??? ? ?? ? ?? ?? ? ?? ? ?? ? ?? ?? ? "}]}],
  "result_index": 0
}
```

I tried to change model to "en-US_BroadbandModel", even with same wav file, it return English words (although the wav is in Chinese).  In this case, I think "model" setting does affects.

But in Response, I can see local is `en_US`.

Any way to set language?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an issue with the console output encoding used by Java in Windows.

Default console output encoding on Windows is not *UTF-8* but [CP850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850).

Use a PrintStream with an explicit encoding to view the the results.

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.

I was using java-sdk-java-wrapper-1.1.0, the problem looks problem in ResponseUtil.getString(HttpResponse response) for line:
return EntityUtils.toString(entity,"UTF-8");

When I change it to following code to use IOUtils.copy instead of EntityUtils, problem is gone.
 InputStream resContent = entity.getContent();
 StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
 String encoding = "UTF-8";
 IOUtils.copy(resContent, writer, encoding);
        String result = writer.toString();
 resContent.close();
 writer.close();
 return result;

Comment: I've open an issue to investigate this https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk/issues/117 Can you please provide there a sample file to use when testing? I want to make sure we fix your issue